# Can someone please tell me why this code does not wanna run. The loop seems to have problems but nothing else

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, menu, submenu

Create a COVID-19 support service application using Python named
CovidSupportSystem that will provide the user with the below options:

```
• Statistics,
• Prevention,
• Symptoms,
• Treatment and Report case
```

The sample output is as follows:

1.1 Under Statistics state how many cases there are in SA, China and USA, then ask
the user if they would like to see the cases for a different country, if yes, ask
them to pick a number between 0 and 9, then pull a country from a list to show
the user, The sample output is as follows:

1.2 Under Prevention place general COVID19 prevention information, as shown below:

1.3 Under Symptoms place general COVID19 Symptoms, such as the following:

1.4. Under Treatment place general COVID19 Treatment, such as the following:

1.5. Under Report case ask the user if they have any of the symptoms, if no, then
state they do not have COVID19, if yes, then ask the user if they have a
temperature above 38.5°C, if no, then state they do not have COVID19, if
yes, ask them to choose which country, USA, SA or China, after they have
decided, the number of infection should increase in that country with 1
(indicated in question 1.2):

1.6. The exit option will close the program

```
def get_menu_choice():
    def print_menu():       # Your menu design here
        print(30 * "-", "Welcome to the COVID 19 support service. Please select and option", 30 * "-")
        print("1. Statistics ")
        print("2. Prevention ")
        print("3. Symptoms")
        print("4. Treatment ")d
        print("5. Report Case ")
        print("6. Exit ")
        print(73 * "-")

        loop = True
        int_choice = -1

        while loop:
            get_menu_choice()
            choice = input("Enter Choice(1/2/3/4/5/6/)")

            if choice == '1':
                choice = ''
                while len(choice) == 0:
                    print("Statistics""\n"
                          "Currently in SA there are 1,843,572 confirmed cases""\n"
                          "Currently in Usa there are 34,434,803 confirmed cases""\n"
                          "Currently in China there are 91,653 confirmed cases""\n")
                    loop = False
                    while loop:
                        print_menu()
                        choice = input("Would you like to see the statistics of a random country.Y/N")
                    int_choice = 1
                    if choice == 'Y' or 'y':
                        choice = ''
                        while len(choice) == 0:
                            choice = input("To select a country, type a number from 0 to 9 or type 10 to exit")
                        int_choice = y or Y
                        loop = False
                        if choice == '0':
                            choice = ''
                            while len(choice) == 0:
                                print("Australia has 30,380 confirmed cases")
                                int_choice = 0
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '1':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("Fiji has 2,270 confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '2':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("India has 30,434,709 confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '3':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("Brazil has 18,056,639 confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '4':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("SA has 1,843,572 confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '5':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("UK has 4,651,988 confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '6':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("China has 91,653 confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '7':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("Iran has 3,128,395 confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '8':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("USA has 34,434,803 confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '9':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("Congo has 12,404 confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '10':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("Exiting")
                            loop = False
                        else:
                            input("Wrong number. Press any key to try again")
                        if End:
                            return [int_choice, choice]

                    elif choice == 'n' or 'N':
                        int_choice = -1
                        print("Exiting")
                        loop = False
                    else:
                        input("Wrong value. Press any key to try again")
                        loop = False
                    if End:
                        return [int_choice, choice]
                        loop = False
                        loop = False
            elif choice == '2':
                choice = ''
                int_choice = -1
                print("Prevention.""\n""\n"
                      "To Prent the spread of COVID 19.""\n"
                      "Clean your hands often. Use soap and water, or an alcohol-based hand rub. At least 70% alcohol."
                      "\n"
                      "Maintain a safe distance from anyone who is coughing or a sneezing.""\n"
                      "Don't touch your eyes, nose or mouth.""\n"
                      "Cover your nose and mouth with your bent elbow or a tissue when you cough or sneeze.""\n"
                      "Stay Home if you feel unwell""\n"
                      "If you have a fever, cough and difficulty breathing, seek medical attention. All in advance.""\n"
                      "Follow the directions of your local health authority.")
                loop = False
            elif choice == '3':
                int_choice = -1
                print("Symptoms""\n""\n"
                      "Most common symptoms:"
                      "Fever"
                      "dry cough"
                      "tiredness""\n"
                      "Less common symptoms"
                      "aches and pains"
                      "sore throat"
                      "diarrhoea"
                      "conjunctivitis"
                      "headache"
                      "loss of taste or smell"
                      "a rash on skin, or discolouration of fingers or toes""\n"
                      "Serious symptoms:"
                      "difficulty breathing or shortness of breath"
                      "chest pain or pressure"
                      "loss of speech or movement")
                loop = False
            elif choice == '4':
                int_choice = -1
                print("Treatment""\n"'\n'
                      "If you feel sick you should rest, drink plenty of fluid, and eat nutritious food. Stay in a "
                      "separate room form other family members, and use a dedicated bathroom if possible. Clean and "
                      "disinfect frequently used surfaces")
                loop = False
            elif choice == '5':
                choice = ''
                while len(choce) == 0:
                    choice = input("Do you have any of the symptoms?y/n")
                while loop:
                    print_menu()
                    choice = input("Do you have any of the symptoms?Y/N")

                int_choice = 5
                loop = False
                if choice == 'y' or 'Y':
                    choice = ''
                    while len(choice) == 0:
                        choice = input("Is your temperature above 38.5C? y/n")
                    int_choice = y or Y
                    loop = False
                    if choice == 'y' or 'Y':
                        choice = ''
                        while len(choice) == 0:
                            choice = input("In which country is the case""\n"
                                           "1.SA""\n"
                                           "2.USA""\n"
                                           "3.China""\n"
                                           "4 Exit""\n"
                                           "enter option(1/2/3/4)")
                        int_choice = y or y
                        loop = False
                        if choice == '1':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("Currently in SA there are" '1,843,572 +1' "confirmed cases""\n")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '2':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("Currently in Usa there are" '34,434,803 + 1' "confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '3':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("Currently in China there are" '91,653 + 1' "confirmed cases")
                            loop = False
                        elif choice == '4':
                            int_choice = -1
                            print("Exiting.....")
                            loop = False
                        else:
                            input("Wrong number. Enter any key to try again")
                        if End:
                            return [int_choice, choice]
                    elif choice == 'N' or 'n':
                        int_choice = -1
                        print("exiting.......")
                        loop = False
                    else:
                        input("Wrong selection. Enter any key to try again")
                    if End:
                        return [int_choice, choice]
                elif choice == 'n' or 'N':
                    int_choice = -1
                    print("Exiting.....")
                    loop = False
                else:
                    input("Wrong selection, Enter any key to try again")
                if End:
                    return [int_choice, choice]
            elif choice == '6':
                int_choice = -1
                print("Exiting....")
                loop = False
            else:
                input("Wrong selection, Enter any key to try again")
                loop = False
            if End:
                return [int_choice, choice]


print(get_menu_choice())
```

Comment: You are asking us to read all of this code, work out what you expect it to do (which is hard because it apparently doesn't do what you expect), and then tell you how to fix it.  Please explain what you expect and how this is different from what it does.

Comment: first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`.

Comment: if this is code with originial indentations then you have wrong indentations.

Comment: i did. No matter what i do it wont work.

Comment: in PYcharm its the right indentation

Comment: `wont work` is the most useless information. You have to describe it. Don't expect that will will run code to see this problem. Do you get error message? Add it in question. Do you get empty string - you should mention this in question.

Comment: if in question you have the same indentation as in PyCharm then it is NOT correct indentation - you have all code inside `print_menu` which is never executed. Better put `print_menu` outside `get_menu_choice` and it will be more readable.

Comment: to make code more readable and simpler to search mistake you could put every option in separated function.

Comment: the loop before the elif choice = 2 is giving trouble. cant discribe it